# What are the 1,500 chengyu for the 2015 chengyu convention

Tags: chengyu

The 2015 Chengyu Convention apparently tested contestants on 1,500 different chengyu.

Where's the list of the 1,500 Chengyu?

Comment: Just for clarification you mean the 1500 that are supposedly associated with 邯郸?

Comment: What is the Chengyu Convention?  Does it have some other more common name?

Comment: 央视《中国成语大会》邯郸开机 1500条成语为赛题  @Ringil

Comment: @ColinMcLarty 《中国成语大会》

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list appears accessible [here](http://fanwen.geren-jianli.org/564160.html).  In total there are 1352 (level 1) + 801 (level 2) + 702 (level 3) = 2855 chengyu.

#### Level 1: 1352 words

```
日以继夜 如痴如醉 如雷灌耳 三番五次 仁人志士 日久天长
风和日丽 三更半夜 其势汹汹 魂飞魄散 饶有兴味 惹事生非
三年五载 山崩地裂 舍死忘生 身价百倍 生搬硬套 冥思苦想
婆婆妈妈 破罐破摔 脉脉含情 目不邪视 装腔作势 明查暗访
老王卖瓜 精雕细琢 假模假式 恼羞成怒 混世魔王 称心如意
路不拾遗 安如磐石 疾风骤雨 孤苦伶仃 茫无头绪 生龙活虎
见景生情 借酒消愁 金璧辉煌 仅此而已 凌乱不堪 零七八碎
面黄肌瘦 名不符实 光明磊落 没精打采 泛泛而谈 见机而行
连绵不绝 良辰吉日 落叶归根 满腔热忱 轮流做庄 见风使舵
旧地重游 口干舌焦 枯燥无味 苦尽甜来 老眼昏花 假戏真做
宾客如云 风靡一时 交口称颂 焦灼不安 尽心竭力 寸草春晖
词穷理屈 蜂拥而上 飞针走线 花枝招展 欢声如雷 刮目相看
红颜薄命 闭门造车 吉凶未卜 话不投机 多多益善 不共戴天
告老还乡 祸从口出 画饼充饥 不堪入目 本性难移 不谋而合
独当一面 兵临城下 鸡犬升天 各执一词 点石成金 众望所归
地广人稀 画蛇添足 别来无恙 鸡犬不宁 虎落平阳 参差不齐
宾至如归 杯盘狼藉 不亦乐乎 虎视眈眈 喋喋不休 不知所措
逢凶化吉 呆若木鸡 得不偿失 不能自拔 大庭广众 不自量力
安营扎寨 单枪匹马 闭门思过 泰然自若 他山之石 驷马难追
昙花一现 随声附和 肆无忌惮 完璧归赵 天伦之乐 泰山压顶
似曾相识 肃然起敬 望洋兴叹 谈虎色变 耸人听闻 天网恢恢
体无完肤 窈窕淑女 万人空巷 徒劳无功 亡羊补牢 万象更新
卧薪尝胆 言外之意 威风凛凛 听天由命 引以为戒 无可厚非
语重心长 业精于勤 以卵击石 心惊肉跳 幸灾乐祸 有口皆碑
迎刃而解 无计可施 壮志未酬 循规蹈矩 学而不厌 一言九鼎
坐井观天 心急如焚 兴师问罪 似是而非 有口无心 应运而生
言不由衷 心如铁石 物尽其用 远见卓识 虚张声势 叶落归根
一纸空文 咬文嚼字 徇私舞弊 秀色可餐 因循守旧 胸有成竹
众口难调 习以为常 血气方刚 玩世不恭 游手好闲 异曲同工
直言不讳 先声夺人 自强不息 专横跋扈 用心良苦 天涯海角
童言无忌 唯唯诺诺 志同道合 张皇失措 逐鹿中原 危言耸听
优柔寡断 一石二鸟 振振有词 先发制人 因材施教 物以类聚
因地制宜 无地自容 悬崖勒马 相得益彰 原形毕露 雄才大略
振臂一呼 逃之夭夭 自圆其说 唯命是从 无奇不有 推心置腹
推波助澜 螳臂当车 朝不保夕 危在旦夕 脱胎换骨 天衣无缝
微不足道 养精蓄锐 脱颖而出 望而却步 针锋相对 喜从天降
易如反掌 徒有虚名 英姿飒爽 有勇无谋 相依为命 自投罗网
瞻前顾后 责无旁贷 趾高气扬 置之度外 一掷千金 引狼入室
悬而未决 循序渐进 羞愧难当 直截了当 袖手旁观 以身试法
无以复加 掷地有声 众目睽睽 众矢之的 自告奋勇 因人而异
朝三暮四 斩钉截铁 震耳欲聋 一落千丈 有条不紊 在所不辞
遥相呼应 忘乎所以 随机应变 无人问津 于事无补 纨绔子弟
损兵折将 一丘之貉 异军突起 自鸣得意 自欺欺人 天罗地网
欲罢不能 追悔莫及 无往不胜 有目共睹 无懈可击 一劳永逸
形影不离 罪魁祸首 自顾不暇 形迹可疑 转危为安 心安理得
应接不暇 自命不凡 走投无路 严阵以待 图谋不轨 贼喊捉贼
无坚不摧 一波三折 引火烧身 隐姓埋名 无所适从 望尘莫及
天壤之别 指日可待 心驰神往 挤眉弄眼 顺手牵羊 新来乍到
阴差阳错 相安无事 势均力敌 浪迹天涯 惊魂未定 首当其冲
嫁鸡随鸡 水落石出 深不可测 咎由自取 双管齐下 细枝末节
树大招风 苦尽甘来 时运不济 牢不可破 利欲熏心 两肋插刀
开卷有益 里应外合 首屈一指 生离死别 事倍功半 历历在目
来日方长 来者不拒 事半功倍 生死与共 扣人心弦 来者不善
空前绝后 焦头烂额 看破红尘 守株待兔 生死攸关 山呼海啸
津津乐道 乐此不疲 临阵磨枪 十恶不赦 时不再来 溃不成军
溜之大吉 守口如瓶 理所当然 明辨是非 居心不良 手足无措
劳而无功 失之交臂 苦不堪言 雷打不动 老谋深算 乐极生悲
金鸡独立 群龙无首 事不宜迟 良师益友 曲高和寡 黔驴技穷
熟视无睹 酒足饭饱 入情入理 瞒上欺下 事在人为 两小无猜
死不瞑目 轻车熟路 事在必行 千差万别 卖主求荣 锲而不舍
局促不安 如鱼得水 入不敷出 两全其美 两败俱伤 立足之地
事与愿违 前仆后继 灵丹妙药 举手之劳 居高临下 例行公事
入乡随俗 毛手毛脚 否极泰来 誓不两立 淋漓尽致 去伪存真
南辕北辙 水到渠成 举一反三 妙手回春 墨守成规 水涨船高
明目张胆 磨刀霍霍 顺理成章 马不停蹄 聚精会神 屡见不鲜
顺藤摸瓜 满城风雨 津津有味 老调重弹 梦寐以求 屡试不爽
灭顶之灾 瞬息万变 论功行赏 量力而行 口干舌燥 难能可贵
漫无边际 马失前蹄 哭天抹泪 了若指掌 家长里短 妙不可言
若隐若现 料事如神 呕心沥血 茅塞顿开 毛骨悚然 临危不惧
披荆斩棘 毛遂自荐 日复一日 狼狈不堪 美不胜收 面面俱到
狼吞虎咽 另起炉灶 落井下石 如胶似漆 妙趣横生 明媒正娶
络绎不绝 前呼后拥 门庭若市 名不副实 略胜一筹 老态龙钟
流连忘返 精益求精 炉火纯青 乐不可支 渺无人烟 貌合神离
名垂青史 泪如泉涌 略知一二 敬而远之 六神无主 时隐时现
名副其实 落落大方 冷眼旁观 麻木不仁 令人发指 赏心悦目
力不从心 就地取材 琳琅满目 据理力争 排山倒海 明知故犯
神乎其神 摩拳擦掌 良莠不齐 忍辱负重 眉来眼去 居心叵测
漫不经心 平起平坐 面红耳赤 破釜沉舟 宽宏大量 嫁祸于人
慢条斯理 据为己有 江郎才尽 如临大敌 庞然大物 命中注定
卷土重来 简明扼要 家贫如洗 拿手好戏 莫名其妙 眉目传情
眉清目秀 名列前茅 决一雌雄 刻舟求剑 就事论事 家喻户晓
耐人寻味 闷闷不乐 名落孙山 乐不思蜀 绝口不提 价值连城
平白无故 面不改色 匹夫之勇 慷慨解囊 梁上君子 开门见山
侃侃而谈 坚不可摧 面目可憎 烂熟于心 柳暗花明 慷慨陈词
迫不得已 面目全非 气味相投 狼狈为奸 交相辉映 来龙去脉
空口无凭 艰难险阻 迫不及待 弃暗投明 盲人摸象 怒发冲冠
江山如画 迫在眉睫 前车之鉴 目不斜视 寄人篱下 将功补过
骄阳似火 其乐无穷 默不作声 轻装上阵 滥竽充数 情窦初开
口若悬河 接二连三 奇耻大辱 夸大其词 截然不同 难兄难弟
奇装异服 目不转睛 情投意合 街头巷尾 难舍难分 坚忍不拔
目光短浅 人各有志 空中楼阁 夸夸其谈 戒备森严 目光炯炯
三头六臂 开诚布公 念念不忘 近在咫尺 怒目而视 舍近求远
伶牙俐齿 金童玉女 弄假成真 怒火中烧 强词夺理 宁缺毋滥
流言蜚语 紧锣密鼓 弄巧成拙 身不由己 量入为出 离题万里
弥天大谎 尽善尽美 见缝插针 三令五申 金碧辉煌 拍案而起
藕断丝连 深谋远虑 见利忘义 掐头去尾 皮开肉绽 气急败坏
琴棋书画 明察秋毫 经久不息 目瞪口呆 旁观者清 旁若无人
深入浅出 水滴石穿 七手八脚 旁敲侧击 神机妙算 渐入佳境
抛头露面 深思熟虑 建功立业 匹夫有责 默默无闻 妻离子散
妙语连珠 刨根问底 蓬头垢面 披头散发 司空见惯 起死回生
劈头盖脸 将心比心 千篇一律 千丝万缕 千里迢迢 可乘之机
谨小慎微 擒贼擒王 惊心动魄 恰到好处 飘飘欲仙 三生有幸
尽力而为 轻于鸿毛 井井有条 神通广大 任重道远 能言善辩
如出一辙 念念有词 九死一生 十拿九稳 杀一儆百 良药苦口
九霄云外 千载难逢 前仰后合 少年老成 久负盛名 乳臭未干
气喘吁吁 十年寒窗 千钧一发 绝处逢生 寿比南山 三长两短
老生常谈 平铺直叙 久经风霜 前功尽弃 千姿百态 书香门第
取而代之 老当益壮 平心而论 前因后果 泣不成声 受宠若惊
鼠目寸光 锒铛入狱 潜移默化 强颜欢笑 束手无策 全神贯注
琅琅上口 奇谈怪论 举世无双 强人所难 寝食不安 思前想后
轻而易举 情不自禁 丧尽天良 轻重缓急 穷困潦倒 见怪不怪
岂有此理 深恶痛绝 上窜下跳 军令如山 将计就计 始终不渝
稍纵即逝 恰如其分 巧夺天工 见机行事 煽风点火 善罢甘休
轻描淡写 蜻蜓点水 穷凶极恶 如雷贯耳 绝无仅有 盛气凌人
秋高气爽 洁身自好 九牛一毛 绳之以法 如愿以偿 弱不禁风
节衣缩食 举棋不定 视死如归 如释重负 若有所思 打抱不平
说三道四 屈打成招 人高马大 铺天盖地 如获至宝 驾轻就熟
燃眉之急 兢兢业业 食不果腹 七零八落 弱肉强食 丧心病狂
趋利避害 人面兽心 声名狼藉 人心惶惶 尽人皆知 将错就错
青梅竹马 忍气吞声 进退两难 盛情难却 奇花异草 若有所失
生不逢时 披麻带孝 人云亦云 精明强干 水中捞月 疲于奔命
苦口婆心 如坐针毡 结党营私 破绽百出 融会贯通 捶胸顿足
若无其事 立竿见影 青红皂白 倾国倾城 穷山恶水 伤风败俗
惹火烧身 锦囊妙计 水泄不通 七上八下 史无前例 声嘶力竭
手无寸铁 神魂颠倒 人迹罕至 神出鬼没 骄兵必败 手舞足蹈
石沉大海 盛极一时 声情并茂 人人自危 斤斤计较 如醉如痴
数不胜数 神清气爽 水天一色 声泪俱下 人满为患 借题发挥
金石为开 齐头并进 始料不及 如狼似虎 神采奕奕 缓兵之计
锦上添花 闭关锁国 高枕无忧 各抒己见 暗送秋波 半推半就
后生可畏 顾名思义 汗马功劳 反客为主 出人头地 咄咄逼人
奔走相告 本末倒置 反目成仇 虎背熊腰 根深蒂固 机不可失
按部就班 黄粱一梦 八面玲珑 彬彬有礼 吃里扒外 各为其主
浑水摸鱼 打草惊蛇 半斤八两 绘声绘色 耿耿于怀 嗟来之食
从一而终 不拘小节 单刀直入 倒背如流 甘拜下风 土生土长
穷乡僻壤 求同存异 人仰马翻 忍无可忍 如虎添翼 如梦初醒
得意忘形 变本加厉 兵荒马乱 不可思议 背井离乡 并驾齐驱
不识时务 断章取义 当机立断 德高望重 不修边幅 腹背受敌
苟且偷生 飞黄腾达 故弄玄虚 对答如流 公报私仇 跋山涉水
掉以轻心 飞来横祸 不容置疑 风调雨顺 短兵相接 寸步难行
乘虚而入 大海捞针 独树一帜 耳濡目染 残兵败将 三心二意
调兵遣将 搬弄是非 长驱直入 东山再起 趁火打劫 春风满面
光天化日 恨之入骨 不由自主 阿谀奉承 耳目一新 不了了之
恩将仇报 不伦不类 愤世嫉俗 恶贯满盈 风餐露宿 不学无术
稳如泰山 千疮百孔 不省人事 才疏学浅 不计其数 大发雷霆
饱经风霜 弹无虚发 堆积如山 恶语伤人 飞檐走壁 将信将疑
乌合之众 无动于衷 无拘无束 无理取闹 无人之境 雪上加霜
饱经沧桑 出其不意 措手不及 地动山摇 东奔西走 攻无不克
饱经忧患 笨鸟先飞 大同小异 夫唱妇随 高抬贵手 根深叶茂
不可开交 荒无人烟 必由之路 皆大欢喜 近水楼台 井然有序
翻江倒海 繁花似锦 飞禽走兽 非分之想 非同小可 狗急跳墙
狗仗人势 好吃懒做 虎口拔牙 昏昏欲睡 祸从天降 酒囊饭袋
娇小玲珑 交口称赞 穷途末路 伤筋动骨 所向无敌 天昏地暗
拉家带口 拉拉扯扯 临危受命 碌碌无为 乱七八糟 三言两语
落荒而逃 眉飞色舞 眉开眼笑 蒙头转向 靡靡之音 名存实亡
逆来顺受 扭扭捏捏 浓妆艳抹 片甲不留 七拼八凑 挖空心思
姗姗来迟 伤天害理 少见多怪 身败名裂 腾云驾雾 天各一方
俗不可耐 所剩无几 投其所好 文不对题 无所事事 痛快淋漓
天花乱坠 歪打正着 万不得已 微乎其微 未老先衰 无缘无故
无事生非 同归于尽 无足轻重 五大三粗 喜形于色 小家碧玉
望风而逃 闻所未闻 稳操胜券 稳扎稳打 喜上眉梢 同舟共济
天理难容 喜怒无常 小鸟依人 同流合污 小肚鸡肠 心怀叵测
天下无敌 无与伦比 小巧玲珑 兵不厌诈 不毛之地 沉鱼落雁
垂帘听政 铁证如山 听其自然 投机取巧 小题大做 不翼而飞
心灰意懒 兴风作浪 行色匆匆 行之有效 雪中送炭 掩耳盗铃
鸦雀无声 言归正传 安然无恙 百步穿杨 班门弄斧 欺人太甚
息息相关 喜笑颜开 无微不至 五雷轰顶 狐朋狗友 挥金如土
弹尽粮绝 粗茶淡饭 洞房花烛 出口成章 地大物博 患难之交
先入为主 显而易见 相提并论 想方设法 想入非非 逍遥自在
垂涎三尺 寸草不生 大刀阔斧 单刀赴会 弹丸之地 东施效颦
度日如年 返老还童 富可敌国 归心似箭 害群之马 狐假虎威
祸不单行 抱头鼠窜 红杏出墙 不屑一顾 八拜之交 不辞而别
八仙过海 恍然大悟 对症下药 丢盔卸甲 飞蛾扑火 杀鸡取卵
笑逐颜开 辗转反侧 张牙舞爪 仗势欺人 心宽体胖 不知所云
助纣为虐 啼笑皆非 铁石心肠 脱口而出 突如其来 痛哭流涕
闻风丧胆 握手言和 无独有偶 势如破竹 忙里偷闲 平分秋色
情有可原 疾风暴雨 集思广益 既往不咎 风吹草动 借古讽今
拭目以待 脍炙人口 借花献佛 名正言顺 难言之隐 孤注一掷
目不暇接 破镜重圆 适可而止 举目无亲 急功近利 百感交集
乘人之危 含笑九泉 心乱如麻 拖泥带水 饥肠辘辘 蠢蠢欲动
不可理喻 车水马龙 百读不厌 不寒而栗 百无一用 不足挂齿
成人之美 海枯石烂 患得患失 张口结舌 肝胆相照 儿女情长
坐吃山空 两面三刀 臭名远扬 利害得失 见异思迁 劳苦功高
削足适履 万古千秋 叶公好龙 绿草如茵 三五成群 愁眉不展
方兴未艾 别开生面 不言而喻 功亏一篑 诲人不倦 百战不殆
高朋满座 后发制人 叱咤风云 虎头蛇尾 不厌其烦 初露锋芒
道貌岸然 俯首帖耳 百川归海 患难与共 后继无人 按兵不动
出奇制胜 恩重如山 与人为善 锋芒毕露 众口一词 四海为家
短小精悍 各有千秋 自吹自擂 心口如一 自惭形秽 现身说法
虚无缥缈 运筹帷幄 望眼欲穿 蔚然成风 痛定思痛 骁勇善战
舞文弄墨 外强中干 偷梁换柱 仗义执言 无孔不入 眼高手低
一蹴而就 作威作福 知人善任 各行其是 引经据典 天旋地转
勇冠三军 指挥若定 相敬如宾 为富不仁 岁寒三友 挑拨离间
所向披靡 心领神会 正中下怀 天外有天 无功受禄 峥嵘岁月
言为心声 心平气和 朝令夕改 义正辞严 颐指气使 忠贞不渝
天马行空 天从人愿 鱼目混珠 夜不闭户 旗开得胜 一筹莫展
跃跃欲试 志大才疏 走马上任 捕风捉影 煞费苦心 人命关天
投笔从戎 惩恶扬善 锣鼓喧天 快人快语 人心叵测 入木三分
鸟语花香 锦绣前程 日理万机 如履薄冰 空头支票 囊中羞涩
气贯长虹 舍生取义 轻歌曼舞 老气横秋 塞翁失马 三顾茅庐
三思而行 南征北战 兴师动众 深明大义 开源节流 乐善好施
名满天下 目空一切 年富力强 匠心独运 千秋万代 情深义重
巧取豪夺 惊涛骇浪 鹏程万里 千头万绪 人多势众 扶老携幼
出生入死 成群结队 不远万里 安分守己 不同凡响 后顾之忧
风雨同舟 高谈阔论 感人肺腑 高不可攀 防患未然 知恩图报
风云人物 感慨万千 高瞻远瞩 花好月圆 大显身手 得意洋洋
山光水色 而立之年 心潮澎湃 扬眉吐气 百年大计 动人心弦
百年树人 赤子之心 数一数二 杀气腾腾 山珍海味 生死相依
自掘坟墓 事出有因 熟门熟路 心明眼亮 自食其力 言过其实
一鸣惊人 引人入胜 坐立不安 才子佳人 窃窃私语 山重水复
一本正经 随行就市 水清无鱼 大兴土木 一蹶不振 市井小人
自食其言 信口开河 意犹未尽 携老扶幼 沾亲带故 志得意满
一挥而就 浩然之气 隔窗有耳 窗明几净 棋逢对手 青云直上
素不相识 羊入虎口 叶落知秋 书声琅琅 评头品足 风云变幻
一马平川 众志成城 言归于好 心腹之患 湖光山色 原封不动
自暴自弃 山高路远 海底捞针 有气无力 万古流芳 顺水推舟
一语道破 衣锦还乡 势不两立 心急火燎 严丝合缝 矢志不渝
无米之炊 装聋作哑 声威大震 中西合璧 言而有信 世风日下
名符其实 鸣冤叫屈 扫地出门 轻如鸿毛 仁至义尽 势不可挡
失魂落魄 睡眼惺忪 无可救药 水深火热 醉生梦死 自以为是
一日三秋 郑重其事 横眉立目 犹豫不决 金玉良言 纸醉金迷
千娇百媚 挑肥拣瘦 十指连心 随波逐流 文山会海 只字不提
一诺千金 纸上谈兵 朝发夕至 整装待发 罪有应得 寸长尺短
座无虚席 迎风招展 羽翼未丰 倚老卖老 抓耳挠腮 阳关大道
下井投石 卸磨杀驴 纵横驰骋 足智多谋 平地青云 损人利己
远交近攻 怨声载道 年深月久 低眉顺眼 身临其境 百废俱兴
将功折罪 春色满园
```

#### Level 2: 801 words

```
鼎足而立 依然固我 长篇累牍 字斟句酌 丧魂落魄 秋毫无犯
郁郁寡欢 鱼贯而入 略表寸心 瘦骨伶仃 虚席以待 酸文假醋
兼济天下 千金一掷 凄风冷雨 金玉其外 襟怀坦白 进退无门
冰肌玉骨 急转直下 学以致用 授受不亲 一言蔽之 至善至美
言必有据 人老珠黄 煞有介事 瘦骨嶙峋 束手就擒 毋庸置疑
置身事外 另当别论 屡次三番 力排众议 来路不明 片言只语
晓行夜宿 搜肠刮肚 霄壤之别 无伤大雅 谈笑自若 图穷匕见
世态炎凉 偃武修文 抑扬顿挫 始乱终弃 声色犬马 生杀予夺
春风化雨 赤县神州 浮光掠影 挂一漏万 积习难除 巧言如簧
品头论足 权衡轻重 坚贞不渝 刀光剑影 倾巢而出 卿卿我我
内外交困 集腋成裘 五行八作 文从字顺 以观后效 起承转合
高山流水 四平八稳 送往迎来 虽死犹生 外柔内刚 得心应手
萎靡不振 含糊其辞 悉听尊便 险象环生 循循善诱 气吞山河
遁入空门 文以载道 物力维艰 闭门谢客 不白之冤 赤膊上阵
岿然不动 离群索居 漠然置之 面授机宜 风烛残年 春寒料峭
欲擒故纵 相映成趣 中流砥柱 载舟覆舟 假公济私 七情六欲
蝇头小利 落花流水 内忧外患 讲古论今 抛砖引玉 强弩之末
忘年之交 天作之合 加官进爵 街谈巷议 求全责备 捷足先登
杞人忧天 矫揉造作 监守自盗 临危授命 力挽狂澜 矫枉过正
青出于蓝 金口玉言 清规戒律 劫富济贫 明升暗降 离情别绪
举重若轻 清心寡欲 劫后余生 人杰地灵 酒色财气 绿林好汉
狂犬吠日 乐不可言 冷暖自知 气象万千 请君入瓮 千虑一失
冷言冷语 冷若冰霜 杀身成仁 开山鼻祖 离经叛道 令行禁止
犬牙交错 口蜜腹剑 殊途同归 礼尚往来 群魔乱舞 流芳百世
立锥之地 量才录用 令出必行 日月如梭 量体裁衣 揭竿而起
束手待毙 时过境迁 计上心来 泾渭分明 落地有声 门户之见
井底之蛙 目无尊长 美玉无瑕 死不足惜 浓墨重彩 披星戴月
民脂民膏 明来暗去 金玉满堂 南腔北调 怒不可遏 逆水行舟
临渊羡鱼 老骥伏枥 神来之笔 思如泉涌 见贤思齐 宝刀不老
形销骨立 兴味索然 锱铢必较 信口雌黄 浅尝辄止 不置可否
百口莫辩 暗度陈仓 大言不惭 隔靴搔痒 步步为营 豁然开朗
厚此薄彼 安步当车 不速之客 风尘仆仆 刚柔相济 哀兵必胜
鞍马劳顿 触类旁通 不可名状 安之若素 乘龙快婿 威德相济
尔虞我诈 泛泛之交 鼻息如雷 睹物思人 沁人心脾 深居简出
见仁见智 口口声声 灰飞烟灭 过犹不及 两相情愿 去粗取精
富甲一方 江河日下 索然无味 忐忑不安 未能免俗 不苟言笑
隔墙有耳 滴水不漏 大放厥词 绰绰有余 不期而遇 风卷残云
过眼烟云 攻其不备 何足挂齿 火中取栗 残花败柳 恩威并用
闪烁其词 人声鼎沸 穷年累月 潸然泪下 戛然而止 旷日持久
画地为牢 囫囵吞枣 路人皆知 空穴来风 口出不逊 接踵而至
口诛笔伐 蹑手蹑脚 设身处地 判若两人 模棱两可 生吞活剥
牵强附会 经年累月 迥然不同 其貌不扬 旁征博引 勤能补拙
萍水相逢 渺无音讯 九五之尊 了然于心 面面相觑 少安毋躁
死灰复燃 每况愈下 另辟蹊径 满腹经纶 美轮美奂 门可罗雀
酩酊大醉 摩肩接踵 名噪一时 满腹狐疑 踉踉跄跄 茫然若失
狡兔三窟 几次三番 绵里藏针 竭泽而渔 神色自若 硕果仅存
叫苦不迭 世外桃源 始作俑者 如影随形 忍俊不禁 实至名归
两手空空 炯炯有神 寥寥无几 瞒天过海 适得其反 燎原之势
玲珑剔透 举步维艰 扪心自问 鸟尽弓藏 权宜之计 勉为其难
流年似水 漏网之鱼 兼容并蓄 明哲保身 星罗棋布 烟波浩渺
丝丝入扣 身外之物 如日中天 乐而忘返 未雨绸缪 万事亨通
寿终正寝 空空如也 鹦鹉学舌 置若罔闻 泰然处之 义气相投
兴味盎然 正颜厉色 坐以待毙 炙手可热 形影相吊 先见之明
轩然大波 招贤纳士 万不及一 望文生义 唾手可得 一笑置之
别出心裁 怅然若失 覆水难收 肺腑之言 风声鹤唳 推己及人
蛊惑人心 处变不惊 车载斗量 陈词滥调 过目成诵 因陋就简
瞠目结舌 裹足不前 鬼斧神工 相去咫尺 虚位以待 死有余辜
安贫乐道 残垣断壁 饱学之士 避重就轻 乘兴而来 丑态百出
黄道吉日 东窗事发 避人耳目 博闻强记 大家风范 相机行事
察言观色 大千世界 雕梁画栋 独善其身 听而不闻 蔚为大观
无所用心 外圆内方 饮水思源 以德报怨 一言兴邦 天荒地老
偃旗息鼓 择善而从 坦然自若 知遇之恩 坐享其成 下里巴人
秀外慧中 虚怀若谷 愚不可及 冰雪聪明 四海升平 枕戈待旦
憨态可掬 词不达意 无庸讳言 扬汤止沸 微言大义 贻笑大方
望其项背 忧心如焚 心无二用 一无所长 仗义疏财 四面楚歌
咫尺天涯 我行我素 因噎废食 行成于思 正襟危坐 吟风咏月
指桑骂槐 瑕不掩瑜 童叟无欺 心向往之 同室操戈 闻风而至
言犹在耳 似水流年 威信扫地 偷天换日 昭然若揭 囤积居奇
心手相应 原原本本 未卜先知 一文不名 心力交瘁 修旧利废
妄自尊大 作茧自缚 欲壑难填 提纲挈领 谈笑风生 弦外之音
仙风道骨 五内俱焚 恣意妄为 欲盖弥彰 跃然纸上 天怒人怨
素昧平生 望穿秋水 桀骜不驯 旁门左道 招摇过市 狭路相逢
七窍生烟 救民水火 气宇轩昂 平步青云 节外生枝 盘根错节
老马识途 金科玉律 决胜千里 绝情寡义 人尽其才 僧多粥少
三十而立 康庄大道 山南海北 礼贤下士 软硬兼施 手足之情
肝肠寸断 破涕为笑 是非曲直 身先士卒 迷途知返 事必躬亲
如花似玉 旷世奇才 任人唯亲 如数家珍 得天独厚 独具慧眼
流离失所 龙马精神 守身如玉 药到病除 百折不挠 刀耕火种
不辞劳苦 盗亦有道 不合时宜 百炼成钢 标新立异 多事之秋
川流不息 浮想联翩 别有用心 重整旗鼓 呼之欲出 兵多将广
反唇相讥 反戈一击 出类拔萃 骇人听闻 风华正茂 逢场作戏
苟延残喘 含辛茹苦 避虚就实 粗枝大叶 毕恭毕敬 慈眉善目
高风亮节 鼎力相助 跌宕起伏 颠沛流离 黯然失色 唉声叹气
好大喜功 独占鳌头 愤愤不平 兵精粮足 不解之缘 碍手碍脚
不可多得 大惊失色 登峰造极 悲欢离合 大动干戈 大失所望
急于求成 不偏不倚 别具一格 包罗万象 不动声色 百思不解
长吁短叹 操之过急 不以为然 变幻莫测 财迷心窍 烽火连天
不足为奇 安家落户 不可或缺 居安思危 官官相护 层出不穷
八面威风 拔地而起 成竹在胸 求贤若渴 暗无天日 茶余饭后
避实就虚 宾客盈门 博学多才 不出所料 波澜壮阔 不可胜数
承前启后 触目惊心 重蹈覆辙 重见天日 除暴安良 当断则断
承上启下 垂死挣扎 春华秋实 大势已去 粗制滥造 粗中有细
低声下气 颠倒是非 耳闻目睹 防不胜防 熙熙攘攘 堂而皇之
感激涕零 高深莫测 攻守同盟 借尸还魂 今是昨非 金字招牌
锦绣山河 好自为之 后患无穷 花容月貌 花天酒地 欢呼雀跃
众星捧月 纤尘不染 月白风清 万全之策 土崩瓦解 销声匿迹
珠联璧合 一概而论 哑然失笑 心悦诚服 相濡以沫 物极必反
衣冠楚楚 摇尾乞怜 舍本逐末 中庸之道 行云流水 嘘寒问暖
探囊取物 委曲求全 言简意赅 不能自已 特立独行 小国寡民
违心之论 笑容可掬 先礼后兵 嬉笑怒骂 玩物丧志 为虎作伥
洋洋大观 天造地设 温文尔雅 一暴十寒 言之有物 一叶知秋
畏首畏尾 游刃有余 一家之言 杳无人烟 惟妙惟肖 无师自通
挥汗如雨 饥寒交迫 半路出家 楚楚动人 大权旁落 大声疾呼
焕然一新 回味无穷 回心转意 老弱残兵 积年累月 吉星高照
假仁假义 酒后失言 看风使舵 空洞无物 弥天大罪 名流轶事
两面夹攻 零敲碎打 流芳千古 龙潭虎穴 痛不欲生 借刀杀人
明眸皓齿 南来北往 七长八短 千恩万谢 青山绿水 头重脚轻
三亲六故 山明水秀 善男信女 擅离职守 深知灼见 河东狮吼
声东击西 师道尊严 十冬腊月 死得其所 坦诚相见 晚节不保
得胜还朝 夺眶而出 法不责众 凡夫俗子 俯首听命 叹为观止
反复无常 风花雪月 福无双至 互通有无 花花世界 欢喜若狂
改头换面 功成名就 里外夹攻 孤立无援 骨肉团圆 固执己见
花前月下 荷枪实弹 横七竖八 后继有人 厚颜无耻 胡作非为
指鹿为马 溢于言表 听之任之 心不在焉 余音绕梁 休养生息
洗耳恭听 心有余悸 鱼龙混杂 心旷神怡 心照不宣 以己度人
庸人自扰 芸芸众生 吐故纳新 味同嚼蜡 鲜为人知 庖丁解牛
反朴归真 体贴入微 指名道姓 古色古香 危机四伏 百废待兴
万死不辞 九泉之下 为人师表 为民请命 闲言碎语 旭日东升
兴利除害 喜新厌旧 先睹为快 相见恨晚 白头偕老 无可名状
天塌地陷 添砖加瓦 轻举妄动 挑三拣四 望而生畏 废寝忘食
勾心斗角 横征暴敛 哗众取宠 急中生智 百家争鸣 雨后春笋
蒸蒸日上 通情达理 张冠李戴 推三阻四 痛心疾首 任人唯贤
误入歧途 识文断字 细水长流 励精图治 飞沙走石 忠心耿耿
嫉恶如仇 好逸恶劳 风起云涌 吹毛求疵 各得其所 好为人师
一片冰心 青黄不接 偏听偏信 气冲霄汉 将遇良才 老牛破车
穷家富路 三教九流 神气活现 顺水人情 沙里淘金 包藏祸心
悲从中来 层峦叠嶂 长风破浪 大义凛然 独断专行 信誓旦旦
妒贤嫉能 歌舞升平 格格不入 各自为战 各自为政 法出多门
广开言路 赫赫有名 古为今用 积土成山 借坡下驴 离心离德
流星赶月 惊魂不定 旧愁新恨 清水衙门 嫉贤妒能 摇唇鼓舌
切中时弊 聚沙成塔 借古喻今 名利兼收 妙笔生花 生生不已
伯仲之间 坐收渔利 助桀为虐 相辅相成 以怨报德 众怒难犯
尚方宝剑 风流韵事 垂涎欲滴 创业维艰 蛇蝎心肠 浪迹萍踪
前无古人 著书立说 急中智生
```

#### Level 3: 702 words

```
覆车之鉴 风姿绰约 扶摇直上 贩夫走卒 反躬自问 不甚了了
并蒂芙蓉 别无二致 搜索枯肠 拾遗补阙 扶危济困 风流倜傥
以儆效尤 残篇断简 不咎既往 穷极无聊 师出有名 无庸置辩
明火执杖 冥顽不化 嘉肴美馔 疾声厉色 机关算尽 解铃系铃
穷则思变 煮豆燃萁 条分缕析 寥若晨星 私相授受 冰释前嫌
谷贱伤农 按迹循踪 百里之才 车马盈门 秉烛待旦 残渣余孽
移樽就教 谈笑封侯 没齿不忘 莞尔而笑 鞠躬如仪 沉渣泛起
文贵天成 降格以求 汪洋恣肆 洞若观火 梦笔生花 千金买笑
镂骨铭心 绿肥红瘦 金刚怒目 论短道长 文不加点 厚今薄古
兼善天下 金玉之言 龙骧虎步 厚积薄发 呼天抢地 公诸同好
明日黄花 以管窥天 金枝玉叶 枯木死灰 未竟之志 独辟蹊径
电光火石 雕栏玉砌 闻鸡起舞 无病呻吟 洗心革面 剑拔弩张
约法三章 薪尽火传 信笔涂鸦 济济一堂 兼收并蓄 理屈词穷
同病相怜 退避三舍 文过饰非 左右逢源 无济于事 物是人非
驽马十驾 审时度势 如临深渊 人心向背 趋之若鹜 望梅止渴
克己奉公 绿叶成荫 买椟还珠 七步成章 兼听则明 雾里看花
文章盖世 卧不安席 污泥浊水 诬良为盗 有恃无恐 随遇而安
无关宏旨 博古通今 跬步千里 落笔千言 债台高筑 文质彬彬
为恶不悛 妄自菲薄 语焉不详 人困马乏 惊人之笔 林林总总
孜孜不倦 喧宾夺主 阳春白雪 一衣带水 衣衫褴褛 五体投地
出言不逊 嗤之以鼻 寡不敌众 慌不择路 晨钟暮鼓 心猿意马
鼎足之势 豆蔻年华 釜底抽薪 孤陋寡闻 白山黑水 病入膏肓
化险为夷 鸣金收兵 轻财重义 文治武功 恬不知耻 抱薪救火
心旌摇曳 言传身教 兔死狗烹 爱莫能助 杯水车薪 不识一丁
晓以利害 无耻之尤 勾魂摄魄 胸无点墨 相得甚欢 鬼迷心窍
物竞天择 息事宁人 喜不自胜 先知先觉 海底捞月 无隙可乘
物阜民安 畏敌如虎 温情脉脉 下笔千言 心腹之交 兴废存亡
跳梁小丑 通宵达旦 彤云密布 添枝加叶 天诛地灭 四海鼎沸
徒费唇舌 推崇备至 万劫不复 枉费唇舌 望风披靡 片瓦不存
徒劳往返 锦衣玉食 围城打援 娓娓而谈 显山露水 摇曳生姿
徒乱人意 泰山北斗 玩火自焚 望风响应 为人作嫁 暴殄天物
审己度人 生灵涂炭 犬马之劳 奇文共赏 世代书香 良辰美景
暮气沉沉 拿贼见赃 年深日久 装神弄鬼 千夫所指 乱臣贼子
门禁森严 宽大为怀 将勤补拙 见神见鬼 老迈年高 老成持重
急不择言 夹七夹八 疾风劲草 扪心无愧 济世之才 慷慨悲歌
魂不附体 和颜悦色 化为乌有 济世安民 教学相长 毁于一旦
过门不入 刚正不阿 放荡不羁 功德圆满 比比皆是 低吟浅唱
当头棒喝 攻城略地 沸沸扬扬 独步当时 咄咄怪事 骨肉相残
翻云覆雨 不得要领 豺狼当道 超凡脱俗 从中作梗 大厦将倾
不见经传 兵戎相见 薄情寡义 沉吟不决 国色天香 魂牵梦绕
不可言传 超然物外 猝不及防 摧眉折腰 蹉跎岁月 大梦初醒
汗牛充栋 手不释卷 舐犊情深 秘而不宣 付之东流 删繁就简
大方之家 差强人意 党同伐异 痴人说梦 顶礼膜拜 吉人天相
何去何从 幡然悔悟 肝脑涂地 风驰电掣 鬼使神差 防微杜渐
处心积虑 冰清玉洁 百无聊赖 耳熟能详 不时之需 感恩戴德
恃强凌弱 束之高阁 蚍蜉撼树 哀鸿遍野 耳提面命 呼朋引类
视如草芥 雷霆万钧 鸣锣开道 少不更事 力不胜任 苦心孤诣
视如粪土 磨杵成针 适逢其会 恃才傲物 临渴掘井 授人以柄
视若路人 南柯一梦 说东道西 流光溢彩 身无长物 奴颜婢膝
身体力行 妙手空空 声名鹊起 狼烟四起 神鬼莫测 声色俱厉
锐不可当 浪子回头 乐天知命 立身扬名 略见一斑 若即若离
如泣如诉 琼浆玉液 群贤毕至 连篇累牍 人微言轻 日甚一日
流水不腐 厉兵秣马 趋炎附势 精兵简政 坚甲利兵 鹿死谁手
曲意逢迎 居功自傲 罄竹难书 三缄其口 金蝉脱壳 木已成舟
魂不守舍 狼子野心 劳燕分飞 巧言令色 经国之才 谦谦君子
借风使船 披肝沥胆 欺人之谈 间不容发 莫可名状 目不识丁
母以子贵 解甲归田 水乳交融 开宗明义 力透纸背 骚人墨客
死而后已 见微知著 莫逆之交 开门揖盗 莫衷一是 牛刀小试
目光如炬 见机而作 马首是瞻 兼而有之 谬种流传 拈轻怕重
金兰之契 劣迹昭昭 落落寡欢 斯文扫地 明火执仗 举案齐眉
民生凋敝 如鸟兽散 另立门户 聊以自慰 老于世故 石破天惊
日薄西山 惊弓之鸟 述而不作 食古不化 怜香惜玉 利令智昏
解民倒悬 琼楼玉宇 谨言慎行 九九归一 久居人下 善自为谋
满目疮痍 蛟龙得水 切磋琢磨 举手投足 蓬荜生辉 惊世骇俗
授业解惑 如法炮制 色厉内荏 失道寡助 拾人牙慧 立地成佛
家无二主 乱世之秋 坚如磐石 孑然一身 金石之言 举止失措
疾言厉色 龙蛇混杂 交杯换盏 千虑一得 悬梁刺股 影影绰绰
无妄之灾 亦步亦趋 子虚乌有 将本求利 缄口不言 龙吟虎啸
玉石不分 隐约其辞 扑朔迷离 要言不烦 引而不发 作法自毙
折戟沉沙 永志不忘 有教无类 凿壁偷光 假以辞色 言不及义
坐而论道 一语破的 鸡鸣狗盗 天公地道 负隅顽抗 枯木逢春
天悬地隔 休戚与共 虚声恫吓 惘然若失 悒悒寡欢 我见犹怜
烜赫一时 万壑争流 仰不愧天 胸无城府 知难行易 繁文缛节
王佐之才 信而有征 无庸赘述 言之凿凿 罪不容诛 万籁俱寂
知人论世 钟灵毓秀 学无常师 诛心之论 相煎何急 鱼贯而行
闻名遐迩 以讹传讹 惴惴不安 修身齐家 睚眦必报 心如止水
形单影只 醍醐灌顶 瓜田李下 天理昭彰 恬淡寡欲 择木而栖
蝇营狗苟 易地而处 衣不解带 支吾其词 心存芥蒂 闲云野鹤
肝胆俱裂 臭名昭著 出尔反尔 唇枪舌剑 唇亡齿寒 道听途说
按图索骥 嗷嗷待哺 草菅人命 不耻下问 曾经沧海 斗转星移
拨云见日 饱食终日 不遗余力 魑魅魍魉 长袖善舞 待价而沽
不假思索 甘居人后 冠冕堂皇 沽名钓誉 惨淡经营 改换门庭
步履维艰 别具匠心 沧海桑田 步履蹒跚 从善如流 不负众望
刚愎自用 不胜枚举 摧枯拉朽 孤芳自赏 混淆视听 有的放矢
固步自封 讳疾忌医 当仁不让 振聋发聩 顾影自怜 功败垂成
穿针引线 藏污纳垢 充耳不闻 峰回路转 耳鬓厮磨 感同身受
卑躬屈膝 闭目塞听 功成身退 奔走呼号 大相径庭 分道扬镳
寅吃卯粮 铁板一块 脱缰之马 兔死狐悲 信马由缰 惜墨如金
仰人鼻息 英雄气短 闻过则喜 抱守残缺 不以为意 穿凿附会
奇货可居 举措失当 曲径通幽 偶一为之 明镜高悬 硕大无朋
人弃我取 乱箭攒心 三人成虎 眉高眼低 十里洋场 山高水长
十室九空 骑马找马 气冲牛斗 日上三竿 巧立名目 鸟枪换炮
平地风波 口不应心 酒酣耳热 敬若神明 如履平地 蜀犬吠日
精卫填海 三纲五常 困兽犹斗 弱不胜衣 上行下效 乐以忘忧
食不甘味 老成练达 双宿双飞 卖官鬻爵 盲人瞎马 大喜过望
馋涎欲滴 壁立千仞 惨绝人寰 纲举目张 殚精竭虑 不足为训
淡泊明志 大而无当 等量齐观 飞扬跋扈 从长计议 不平则鸣
出水芙蓉 敷衍塞责 等闲视之 倒行逆施 飞短流长 不知所终
餐风饮露 踌躇满志 匪夷所思 岌岌可危 不可一世 待人接物
别有洞天 火树银花 俯仰之间 含饴弄孙 黯然销魂 沧海横流
不绝如缕 百无禁忌 荒诞不经 回肠百转 祸国殃民 落草为寇
颠扑不破 甘之如饴 宝马香车 待字闺中 缠绵悱恻 不蔓不枝
积习难改 祸福相椅 不一而足 古道热肠 分崩离析 怪力乱神
恍如隔世 弊绝风清 不揣冒昧 尺短寸长 陈陈相因 屏气凝神
并行不悖 锄强扶弱 春兰秋菊 挥洒自如 花团锦簇 浑然一体
壁垒分明 不即不离 仓皇失措 登坛拜将 等而下之 愁肠百结
横生枝节 穷寇莫追 兴致索然 守望相助 小小不言 一唱三叹
机关用尽 龙肝凤髓 龙眉凤目 龙盘虎踞 脑满肠肥 穷奢极欲
荡气回肠 名士风流 明珠暗投 冥顽不灵 人寿年丰 肉眼凡夫
回天之力 千金一诺 敲骨吸髓 凄风苦雨 欺世盗名 棋逢敌手
如芒在背 三从四德 师出无名 喷薄欲出 痰迷心窍 朝秦暮楚
照本宣科 如日方升 三位一体 天女散花 吞云吐雾 铁树开花
茹毛饮血 三亲六眷 未始不可 象牙之塔 铤而走险 躬逢其盛
同仇敌忾 童心未泯 捉襟见肘 投鼠忌器 投桃报李 侠肝义胆
阳奉阴违 亭亭玉立 缘木求鱼 一叶障目 无稽之谈 闲情逸致
下笔成章 不关痛痒 旷古未闻 管窥之见 光复旧物 积重难返
叠床架屋 俯仰无愧 虎啸风生 兵无常胜 情随事迁 绳锯木断
```

While they claim copyright, they obviously don't hold the copyright (and it's also [here](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/52920276581b6bd97f19eafd.html), [here](https://www.wenkuxiazai.com/doc/a91304d5866fb84ae55c8d2c.html), [here](http://www.zxxk.com/soft/3826417.html), [here](https://max.book118.com/html/2018/0316/157529455.shtm), [here](https://www.taodocs.com/p-145154622.html), etc. (behind various paywalls)), so I'm just going to disregard that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I could find, not sure if its the actual chengyu tested.

[2015年《中国成语大会》海选题库文件](http://www.wenku1.com/view/F0CBDA049210A058.html)